# Python to execute shell and prints the stdout

Tags: python

printing stdout[1] prints only single character. How to print single line instead of single character?

```
pr = subprocess.Popen(args=['./check.sh'], bufsize=1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

(stdout, stderr) = pr.communicate(input=None)

print(stdout[1])
```

Comment: `stdout[1]` will print the **second** character from the output. Just highlighting this fact in case you meant the first one, which would be `stdout[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how your `check.sh` looks.  But if it's something simple, say:

```
#check.sh
echo "foo"
echo "bar"
```

Then you can `decode()` (from bytes to string) and split on newlines (`\n`):

```
stdout.decode().split("\n")[0] # foo
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way that could be faster on large outputs, or when streaming output is to consider [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile)

```
from itertools import takewhile
print("".join(takewhile(lambda x: x != "\n", stdout)))
```

This will keep feeding characters into the join function until it finds a newline character, or the end of the output.

It's worth noting that this specific implementation of the solution will only work with the *first* line of the output - so adjust accordingly.